# Vector subscript out of range multidimensional vector

Tags: c++, vector, multidimensional-array, containers

I´m working on PLY file reader (txt file with vertex and faces position info). It consist of header, vertex positions, faces info.

header

-1 -1 -1 // x y z coordinates

3 1 2 3 // this face consists of 3 vertexes - 1,2,3

After that I draw it with OpenGL.

I made it work with arrays, now I want to use vector container for value saving. Because I don´t have to know size during compilation time.

I initialize my two vectors:

```
vector<string> ply_file;
vector< vector<float> > vertex_list;
```

With ply_file is everything okay, but when i try to write into vertex_list with this code:

```
int j = 0;  
for(int i=first_vertex_row-1;i<first_vertex_row+vertex_number-1;i++)
{       
    std::stringstream ss(ply_file[i]); 
    ss >> vertex_list[j][0] >> vertex_list[j][1] >> vertex_list[j][2]; // x,y,z     
    j++;
}
```

But I get debug assertion fail: vector subscript out of range.

I know that I´m writing it in wrong way, but I am unable to make it work.
Is it possible to write it to multidimensional vector with stringstream? If so, how to achieve it?

Comment: When the assertion happens, what is the values of `i` and `j`? Are the in range for respective vector?

Comment: Make "it" work (with a small code example) for a *one*-dimensional vector, at it will all become clear.

Comment: You didn't show us where you sized the vectors using `vector::push_back`, `vector::insert`, `vector::resize`, etc.  Right now, you declared two empty vectors, and then show code using them as if they were populated with data.  That is not a complete example.

Comment: Ouch, I use vertex_list only at these to lines. I thought that second example is good enough for data writing. So: std::stringstream ss(ply_file[i]); 
    ss >> ... wont push the data in to the vector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`vector< vector<float> > vertex_list;` creates a empty vector.  When you try to insert values into it with

```
ss >> vertex_list[j][0] >> vertex_list[j][1] >> vertex_list[j][2];
```

all of those indexs are out of the bounds of the vector.  In order to add values to the vector like this you need to construct it to the size you want.  For a 2d vector it will have the form of

```
std::vector<std::vector<some_type> some_name(rows, std::vector<some_type>(columns, value));
```

Comment: Yes! That was exactly what I was missing :-). What should 'value' contain?

Comment: @ToKra You can pick whatever but for numeric types I use 0 as the default.

Comment: Thank you, now it works. 
I use this before main:
std::vector< vector<float> > vertex_list(vertex_number, std::vector<float>(3, 0));
in main I use resize:
vertex_list.resize(vertex_number, vector<float>(3));